# Get results from WPDB

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have this scenario that I can't figure out:

Inside table `wp_comment` I need to list all `user_id` (not duplicate) with `comment_type=complete`.

I tried this:

```
$results = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_type='sensei_course_status' AND comment_approved='complete'", ARRAY_A );

$corsisti = $results[user_id];

// I need to print only ids to put this array in
get_users( include=> '$corsisti' )
```

The database screenshot:

[image: screenshot of database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [wpdb::get_col()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col/) method to retrieve an array with values from a single column:

```
$corsisti = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_col( "SELECT `user_id` FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_type='sensei_course_status' AND comment_approved='complete'");
```

Then simply use the result in `get_users` (you do not need the quotes):

```
$users = get_users( include=> $corsisti );
```

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't work. This is the array with var_dump

array(6) { [0]=> string(7) "user_id" [1]=> string(7) "user_id" [2]=> string(7) "user_id" [3]=> string(7) "user_id" [4]=> string(7) "user_id" [5]=> string(7) "user_id" }